# Default monospace font in Qt applications

Tags: debian, fonts, qt, fontconfig

In the file `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` i have set `monospace` to `DejaVuSansMono`:

```
<alias>
  <family>monospace</family>
  <prefer><family>DejaVuSansMono</family></prefer>
</alias>
```

GTK applications (like the text editor Pluma) respect this setting and if I select the font Monospace I get DejaVu Sans Mono. In the Qt application TortoiseHg Workbench, however, the font Monospace is associated with Courier:

[image]

Here are the font settings in TortoiseHg:

[image]

Where do Qt applications retrieve their font associations from?

I can set the font in TortoiseHg to DejaVu Sans Mono but I believe it would be more advantageous to address the underlying issue so that DejaVu Sans Mono becomes the monospace font for all Qt applications. Do you have any suggestions?

I run Debian 12 and TortoiseHg version 6.3.1 which is built with Qt-5.15.8.

**Edit**: Before I installed the package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, DejaVu Sans Mono was the font associated with Monospace in TortoiseHg.

Comment: What is output from `fc-match "monospace"`?

Comment: That's a useful command. The output is `DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"`. Apparently, TortoiseHg is not using this font association.

Comment: It's wired. Your fontconfig has worked as intended. Do all other Qt applications behave the same way?

Comment: Can you show the output from `python -c "from PyQt5.QtGui import QFontDatabase; from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication; app = QApplication([]); print(QFontDatabase.systemFont(QFontDatabase.FixedFont).family())"` ? Of course you'll need python package `PyQt5`, but chances are it's already installed.

Comment: @memchr The output from the command is `monospace`.

Comment: @memchr I tried installing the Qt text editor TEA and when I set the font to Monospace I get DejaVu Sans Mono. Hence, as you say, the problem lies in TortoiseHg.

Comment: It is possible, especially if `TortoiseHg` has hardcoded its font or is installed from a sandboxed source such as AppImage or flatpak.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147064/discussion-between-memchr-and-august-karlstrom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in TortoiseHg:

https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/tortoisehg/thg/-/issues/5911

The obvious workaround is to (explicitly) set the fonts to DejaVu Sans Mono in the TortoiseHg font settings.

Answer (score 0):

Install and run `qt5ct`, or you can directly edit `~/.config/qt5ct/qt5ct.conf`.

Comment: I installed qt5ct and set Fonts -> Fixed width to "Monospace 10" but the monospace font in TortoiseHg is still Courier (even after restarting X11).